# Angular 2, animation trigger has not been registered

Tags: angular

It's the first time I work with Angular 2 animation and I have a little problem with implementation. I used the Angular guide but I have the following error :

```
ERROR Error: The provided animation trigger "menubarState" has not been 
registered!
at AnimationTransitionNamespace._getTrigger (transition_animation_engine.js:239)
at AnimationTransitionNamespace.trigger (transition_animation_engine.js:262)
at TransitionAnimationEngine.trigger (transition_animation_engine.js:896)
at InjectableAnimationEngine.AnimationEngine.process (animation_engine_next.js:146)
at AnimationRenderer.setProperty (animation_renderer.js:500)
at DebugRenderer2.setProperty (services.js:1206)
at setElementProperty (element.js:386)
at checkAndUpdateElementValue (element.js:308)
at checkAndUpdateElementInline (element.js:243)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.js:468)
```

My component code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, transition, style, animate } from 
'@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: "rendez-vous",
  templateUrl: "./composants/rendezVous/rendezVous.html",
  styleUrls: ["./composants/rendezVous/rendezVous.css"],
  animations: [
    trigger("menubarState", [
    state('in', style({height: '*'})),
    transition('* => void', [
      style({height: '*'}),
    animate(250, style({height: 0}))
    ])
  ])]
})
export class rendezVousComposant {

etatAffichage : string = "off";

gestionAffichage () {
  this.etatAffichage = 'in';
}
}
```

My html code :

```html
<div class="rendezVous">
<div (ngClick)="gestionAffichage()">Afficher</div>
<div [@menubarState]="etatAffichage">...</div>
</div>
```

My dependencies :

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.13",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.41"
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 34):

I too encountered with this problem and it was just a **typo**.

I declared the **trigger** with name as **fade** and used in template like **face**

```js
export let fade = trigger('fade', [
    transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(2000)
    ])
])

// here it was the mistake
<div @face></div>
```

That's the reason I was getting this error.

Comment: Not to get nitpicking but is this a syntactical mistake or just a typo?

Comment: @Ya. Thank you, it's typo

Comment: thanks, I put 'blockFade' and 'blockfade' and got the same, your comment helped me realize its just typo :)

Answer (score 6):

The name used in your template must be the name defined as a string, not the property name or exported name.

[image]

So here I have a property `fadeInOutAnimation` but the trigger is actually called `fadeAnimation`.

So you must use `[@fadeAnimation]` in your template, and not `[@fadeInOutAnimation]`. It's probably a best practice for them to match as much as possible.

Comment: exactly this was my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign the trigger declaration with something truthy, like a boolean. As they do in the official tutorial, which you can find [@Angular.IO](https://angular.io/guide/router). Like `menubarState = true` inside your component.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing following in your component:

`@Output() menubarState: string;`

or may be you meant `etatAffichage` instead of `menubarState`

You need to do 3 things for aniimation:

1) Add `animations` and state triggers - which you already did
2) Add output binding on the HTML - which you did `div [@menubarState]="etatAffichage">`
3) Missing: Define `@Output menubarState`

Then you need to change the state of `menubarState` to various values cording to your state trigger.